# convert ISO8601 format to seconds in python without using any external library

Tags: python, datetime, time, iso8601

I am trying to convert ISO8601 time format to seconds/unix/epoch time in python with just using the standard library.

Time format = '2012-09-30T15:31:50.262-08:00'

Basically the time will be a string which it parses and converts it back to seconds.

Slicing and picking the values which we want is possible but is there any better way than this?

```
import datetime, time
def convert_enddate_to_seconds(self, ts):
    """Takes ISO 8601 format(string) and converts into epoch time."""
     dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(ts[:-7],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')+\
                datetime.timedelta(hours=int(ts[-5:-3]),
                minutes=int(ts[-2:]))*int(ts[-6:-5]+'1')
    seconds = time.mktime(dt.timetuple()) + dt.microsecond/1000000.0
    return seconds
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you don't want to use dateutil?

Comment: I do not want to import a library just to convert the time.

Comment: The `datetime` module already comes with Python, you can simply `import` it without needing to download anything. It's difficult to use Python without being willing to use at least the builtin libraries.

Comment: The above implementation works but not as good as the dateutil and the xml.iso8601.parse

Comment: you're already importing `datetime` and `time`; why is `dateutil` any different? Why not do all the math yourself, too?

Comment: No, there isn't going to be a cleaner way without outside libraries, but also your snippet does not work as written. You only want to strip off the last 6 characters, not 7. Also, there are no fractional seconds in your example string, so the `.%f` will throw an exception. In addition, you seem to be adding the timezone offset; instead you should subtract it to get your datetime object in UTC.

Comment: Also, since you just want the number of seconds, use `time.strptime()` instead of `datetime.strptime()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final correct answer after Celada's answer. Below I have verified that the outputs of both the xml.iso8601.parse also returns the same result as the one generated by the function.  Thanks to Celada for providing issues with the original code.

```
>>> import calendar, datetime, time 
>>> def convert_enddate_to_seconds(ts):
...   """Takes ISO 8601 format(string) and converts into epoch time."""
...   dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(ts[:-7],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')-\
...       datetime.timedelta(hours=int(ts[-5:-3]),
...       minutes=int(ts[-2:]))*int(ts[-6:-5]+'1')
...   seconds = calendar.timegm(dt.timetuple()) + dt.microsecond/1000000.0
...   return seconds
... 
>>> import iso8601
>>> ts = '2012-09-30T15:31:50.262-08:00'
>>> iso8601.parse(ts)
1349047910.0
>>> convert_enddate_to_seconds(ts)
1349047910.26
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you have at least 4 bugs in your sample code:

- Your `strptime` format requires a decimal point and digits after the seconds but your sample input doesn't have that.
- The `ts[:-7]` bit doesn't slice the end off the string correctly. `ts[:-6]` would seem more correct: you want to slice 6 characters off the end of the string (2 for the tz hour, 2 for the tz minute, 1 for the :, and 1 for the + or -).
- You are adding the timezone offset where you should be subtracting it instead. You must subtract hours and minutes from a time given in an Eastern hemisphere timezone in order to get back to UTC, not add them.
- You are using `time.mktime()` which assumes the timetuple is given in local time, but it's actually UTC. You need to use `calendar.timegm()` instead.

Here's your code updated to but the latter three problems. The first problem remains, because I did not know if you intended to force the presence of fractional seconds in the input string. You can adjust it further.

```
import datetime, time, calendar

def convert_enddate_to_seconds(ts):
    """Takes ISO 8601 format(string) and converts into epoch time."""
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(ts[:-6],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')-\
                datetime.timedelta(hours=int(ts[-5:-3]),
                minutes=int(ts[-2:]))*int(ts[-6:-5]+'1')
    seconds = calendar.timegm(dt.timetuple()) + dt.microsecond/1000000.0
    return seconds
```

Using `2010-01-04T12:15:30.1+01:00` as test input, I get 1262603730.1 as output, which is correct.

As for your question: no, you are not likely to be able to get much more concise than that if you just confine yourself to the standard library.

Comment: I have edited the time format.  Actually ISO 8601 is below.

ts = '2012-09-30T15:31:50.262-08:00'

This is the correct format.  I have edited my original post.  Thanks for pointing a few mistakes.

The first two issues go away since I did a mistake in giving the input.  Thanks for fixing the 3rd and the 4th issue.

Comment: I have edited my post with the final version of the code.  Thanks Celada.